# Git completion with aliases

Tags: git, zsh, autocomplete

I have a convenient dotfiles repo on Github for you all to look at, [here](https://github.com/cormacrelf/dotfiles/). FYI, git is installed via Homebrew, as with most of the executables on my system.

My git-completion in zsh works fine when I use no aliases, such as:

```
% git add fi<TAB> # => file.rb
```

But if I add an alias in my .zshrc (actually `cormacrelf-dotfiles-repo/zsh/aliases.zsh`), like:

```
alias ga="git add"
compdef _git ga=git-add
```

... trying to complete anything (not just files: branches, etc.) results in an error:

```
% git add fi
_git:19: parse error: condition expected: 1
```

Comment: Did you try "git add fi<tab>' or 'ga <tab>'. Question sounds confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setopt no_complete_aliases` in your `.zshrc`. Yes I know, the name sounds wrong, but that works.

Comment: Legend! This seems to work for me.